# iphone developer programs

Tags: iphone

I want to know the validity of the **Enterprise iPhone developer program**.

is it also one year only ?

Thanking you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The program website clearly states that it costs $299/year.](http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/enterprise/)

Comment: can you tell me the examples at which perticular purposes we should have to choose which program ?

Comment: --is Enterprise program for developing "intranet" like app which we can't give access to outside the company employees ..
--and Standard program is just like as "internet" app which can be distribute to all over the world..

am i correct or not ?

please correct me if i am wrong